# Excel or Google Docs: Plotting instances of dates on line graph

Tags: excel, graph, google-docs

Ahoy everybody, I have a column of about 3000 dates, some duplicates, some not, of when an item was purchased via our website.

I am basically wanting to take the dates and plot them on a line graph or even a scatter graph (yes, it will be VERY wide) to see when the MOST POPULAR buying time is.

The Y value will obviously be the number of instances of the date, and the X value will the dates themselves.

A very short sample size of the data:

```
09-07-2011
01-02-2012
03-02-2012
04-27-2012
05-10-2012
05-18-2012
05-22-2012
05-22-2012
05-22-2012
05-25-2012
05-26-2012
05-27-2012
05-27-2012
06-02-2012
06-16-2012
07-02-2012
07-02-2012
07-03-2012
07-03-2012
07-03-2012
07-03-2012
07-05-2012
07-06-2012
07-06-2012
07-06-2012
07-06-2012
07-06-2012
07-08-2012
07-10-2012
```

As you can see, the dates of 5-22 will have 3 instances, 5-27 will have 2.   But how do I plot this on a graph!?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am on hour 2 and ready to pull me hair out. :)

EDIT: Of course, if I can in some way COUNT the number of unique instances of each date, then I am pretty sure I can make the graph, however, I am not finding the right tutorial either.

Example using sample dataset above:

```
09-07-2011   1
01-02-2012   1
03-02-2012   1
04-27-2012   1
05-10-2012   1
05-18-2012   1
05-22-2012   3
05-25-2012   1
05-26-2012   1
05-27-2012   2
06-02-2012   1
06-16-2012   1
07-02-2012   2
07-03-2012   4
07-05-2012   1
07-06-2012   5
07-10-2012   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating a Pivot Chart (Bar Chart) and adding 'Count of Dates' to your "Values" and then 'Dates' to your "Legend Fields(Series)".

[image]

Comment: YES! That would work perfectly! I think my disconnect is the "Count of Dates" is that an option when setting up a Pivot Chart that I am not seeing?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: @PaulHanak When I drag a date value to the Vaules section it defaults to count for me. If you dont see it then click on the Count of Dates field in the Values list and from the popup select Value Field Settings, there you can choose the summarize value field by calculation you need.